# Strapi: Change values via admin ui of timestamp fields (created_at, updated_at, published_at)

Tags: javascript, strapi

Is it possible to change the values of timestamp fields: `created_at`, `updated_at` and `updated_at` manually from the admin ui?

The table columns for these fields are automatically generated by Strapi for each collection type. I checked the model options, but there is only the option to change their default names:

```json
{
  "options": {
    "timestamps": ["new_created_at_name", "new_updated_at_name"],
    // ...
  }
}
```

Is there a way to set them as an editable field inside the collection type view or do I have to create custom date fields for such a case?

Comment: Hi @sunwarr10r, have you got the answer for this?